# Not all rows are being added to a list in SearchCursor

Tags: python, list, arcpy

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["LAT", "LON"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("Print rows: {} ".format(row)
        xy_list = [(row[0],row[1]) for row in cursor]

print("Print list: {} ".format(xy_list))
```

Output:

```
Print rows: (44.8175669441669, -63.6431023726842) 
Print list: [(44.8175486319183, -63.6432418986223), (44.8170733108224, -63.644658488894)]
```

The feature class I am extracting the Lat, and Long from in the SearchCursor to add to a list has three attributes. I don't understand why aren't all three coordinates being added.

Note: The coordinate that I printed "Print rows: (44.8175669441669, -63.6431023726842) " is not in the List.

Answer (score 0):

You are consuming “cursor” iterable one time in the for loop and then again inside the for body with a list comprehension (second and third time).

It seems like what you want in the end is 
xy_list=list(cursor)

No?

Answer (score 0):

Each row is a tuple, if you want to make a list of rows , you should append this rows as lists to your xy_list:

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\Teste\Teste.gdb\Test_Coord'

xy_list = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ["LAT", "LON"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row
        xy_list.append(list(row))

print("Print list: {} ".format(xy_list))
```